# Excel Macro To Send Specific Info In Multiple Separate Emails

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

So I'm in need of some help. I'm trying to update my company's Excel tool that they use to manage clients. I currently need help with updating the Send Email function of the tool. So employees will have a list of clients they need to send an email to, and each client will have specific information like name, client number, etc., and the employees should be able to click the "Send Email" macro button that's built in, and different emails will populate in Outlook with the specific info for each client built into the Email recipient, Title and Body.

I am currently stuck. For example, I will choose 3 clients to send an email to, click the "Send Email" button, and I will get 3 emails to populate (as I should). The first email will have all of the correct info in the right place for Client #1. However, Email #2 will have the correct Email Recipient & Email Title, but then the Email Body will have the correct info for Client #2, and below that also in the Email Body will be all of the email body info for Client #1. And same for Email #3, it will have the correct recipient and title, but the Body will have body info for Client #3, then Client #2, then Client #1.

So I know that I need to fix it through some sort of loop for the email body, but I have been working on this for so long I just can't see it anymore. I've removed any sensitive information and put in placeholders, but I think you should get the idea.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

```
Sub SendEMail()
Dim Email As String
Dim Subj As String
Dim Msg As String
Dim URL As String
Dim r As Integer
Dim x As Double
Dim OApp As Object
Dim OMail As Variant
Dim Signature As String
Dim strbody As String



strbody = "<html><body>"

With Sheets("Email").Select
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
End With

For r = 2 To lastrow


Set OApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OMail = OApp.CreateItem(0)

'       Get the email address
Sheets("Email").Select
Email = Cells(r, "F")
'       Message subject
Sheets("Email").Select
Subj = "Renewal for " & Cells(r, "B").Text & " Contract " & Cells(r, "A").Text & " Effective " & Cells(r, "C").Text

'       Message body
Sheets("Email").Select
strbody = strbody & "Dear " & Cells(r, "AR").Text & ", <br><br>" & _
"I will be working with you on " & Cells(r, "B") & ", client number " &       Cells(r, "A") & ", which is effective " & Cells(r, "C") & ".<br><br>" & _
"For this year's contract, we are requesting the following information: <br>" & _
"<li>" & Cells(r, "AH") & "</li>" & "<br><br>" & _
"The application form may be downloaded from:<br>" & _
"<li>Option #1</li>: " & "<a href=""" & "Link#1" & """>" &    "Link#1" & "</a>" & "<br>" & _
"<li>Option #2</li>: " & "<a href=""" & "link#2" & """>" & "link#2" & "</a>" & "<br><br>" & _
"Once we receive the requested information, you will receive your contract within 5 business days. Should you have any questions, please don't hesitate to contact me at this email address or phone number <br><br>" & _
"As always, we would like to thank you for your business. <br><br>" & _
"Regards, <br>"

On Error Resume Next

Sheets("Email").Select
With OMail
.Display
.To = Email
.Subject = Subj
.HTMLBody = strbody & vbNewLine & .HTMLBody
End With
Next r

On Error GoTo 0

Set OMail = Nothing
Set OApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Something like a [mail merge](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-mail-merge-to-send-personalized-email-messages-to-your-email-address-list-c49e5cfc-53f9-4ec8-9bd9-1f8f3648f1b7?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this example.

In column A : Names of the people
In column B : E-mail addresses
In column C:Z : Filenames like this C:\Data\Book2.xls (don't have to be Excel files)

The Macro will loop through each row in "Sheet1" and if there is a E-mail address in column B
and file name(s) in column C:Z it will create a mail with this information and send it.

```
Sub Send_Files()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim FileCell As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each cell In sh.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        'Enter the path/file names in the C:Z column in each row
        Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("C1:Z1")

        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            With OutMail
                .to = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Testfile"
                .Body = "Hi " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value

                For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                    If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                        If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                            .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                        End If
                    End If
                Next FileCell

                .Send  'Or use .Display
            End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

    Set OutApp = Nothing
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

You can learn more about it from the link below.

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail6.htm

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use this macro instead of a mail merge the problem you are having is here:

```
strbody = strbody & "Dear " & Cells(r, "AR").Text & ", <br><br>" & _
"I will be working with you on " & Cells(r, "B") & ", client number " &       Cells(r, "A") & ", which is effective " & Cells(r, "C") & ".<br><br>" & _
"For this year's contract, we are requesting the following information: <br>" & _
"<li>" & Cells(r, "AH") & "</li>" & "<br><br>" & _
"The application form may be downloaded from:<br>" & _
"<li>Option #1</li>: " & "<a href=""" & "Link#1" & """>" &    "Link#1" & "</a>" & "<br>" & _
"<li>Option #2</li>: " & "<a href=""" & "link#2" & """>" & "link#2" & "</a>" & "<br><br>" & _
"Once we receive the requested information, you will receive your contract within 5 business days. Should you have any questions, please don't hesitate to contact me at this email address or phone number <br><br>" & _
"As always, we would like to thank you for your business. <br><br>" & _
"Regards, <br>"
```

This takes the variable strbody and **adds** the rest of the string to it.

Update it to:

```
strbody = "Dear " & Cells(r, "AR").Text & ", <br><br>" & _
"I will be working with you on " & Cells(r, "B") & ", client number " &       Cells(r, "A") & ", which is effective " & Cells(r, "C") & ".<br><br>" & _
"For this year's contract, we are requesting the following information: <br>" & _
"<li>" & Cells(r, "AH") & "</li>" & "<br><br>" & _
"The application form may be downloaded from:<br>" & _
"<li>Option #1</li>: " & "<a href=""" & "Link#1" & """>" &    "Link#1" & "</a>" & "<br>" & _
"<li>Option #2</li>: " & "<a href=""" & "link#2" & """>" & "link#2" & "</a>" & "<br><br>" & _
"Once we receive the requested information, you will receive your contract within 5 business days. Should you have any questions, please don't hesitate to contact me at this email address or phone number <br><br>" & _
"As always, we would like to thank you for your business. <br><br>" & _
"Regards, <br>"
```

And it will overwrite it each time which is what I think you want.

Also you don't need to select the sheet each time (or at all really).  Selecting sheets, cells, etc is generally bad coding practice that can significantly slow down your code.

Comment: Yes, thsi works great! Thank you very much for the help and the advice! I'm a beginner, so these tips are great before I actually form the bad habits. Thank you for being so efficient!

Comment: not sure what the downvote was for as it seems to have solved the OP's problem despite it not being accepted.